# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, string

I have a code meant to strim a string within a large text file. When I run it an error message shows up "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack". So I changed the integer for 0, 1 and 2 in this line :

```
    _, k = line.split('\t',1)
```

If I input 2 it says 'Too many value to unpack'. I tried to define each variable as follow :

```
    f = []
    _ = []
    k = []
    x = []
    i = 0
```

.. That didn't work out either.

Here is the code:

```
    # Opens each file to read/modify
    infile='110331_HS1A_1_rtTA.result'
    outfile='2.txt'

    #import Regex
    import re

    with open (infile, mode='r', buffering=-1) as in_f, open (outfile, mode='w', buffering=-1) as out_f:
        f = (i for i in in_f if i.rstrip())
        for line in f:
            _, k = line.split('\t',1)
            x = re.findall(r'^1..100\t([+-])chr(\d+):(\d+)\.\.(\d+).+$',k)
            if not x:
                continue
            out_f.write(' '.join(x[0]) + '\n')
```

Here is the error :

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\DB\Stack Overflow\test5.py", line 11, in <module>
       _, k = line.split('\t',1)
   ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Thanks for those who are willing to help/teach me :)

Comment: yeah, check out the output of ` _, k = "ab".split('\t',1)` vs ` _, k = "a\tb".split('\t',1)`

Comment: @Andrew White : I changed it for `_, k = "a\tb".split('\t',1)`, there's no error message but the output file is empty T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, that's the code I wrote on the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673917/inconsistent-indentation-with-python-after-split/6674086#6674086). You could have asked there...

Since the file you gave didn't had any non-empty lines without `tab`, i assumed there would be no problem.

You can check if there's any tab character in the line by changing this one:

```
f = (i for i in in_f if i.rstrip())
```

to

```
f = (i for i in in_f if '\t' in i.rstrip())
```

So you'll remove empty lines and also those without the `'\t'`.
To see the line of your file having that problem, you can do (using the original code):

```
try:
    _, k = line.split('\t',1)
except:
    print(line)
```

BTW, the `_` is often used to things we don't care in some operation. It can have any name.

```
ATCGATTTCG....ATGC    1..100blablabla
       ^                     ^
 useless part (_)     important one (k)
```

Comment: sorry i did but i though that you wouldn't see it anymay.. and this is really urgent T.T Anyway Thanks for your help, I'll try this in a couple of minutes and let you know.

Comment: Good Morning, I changed f for `f = (i for i in in_f if '\t' in i.rstrip())` That worked out well, no error message and the output file contained all information separated by a space character.

Comment: @madkitty if you want a tab character to separate, just change at the last line where it says `' '.join(...` to `'\t'.join(...`

Answer (score 2):

You hit a line that doesn't contain `\t`, hence the resultant list only has one element.

Comment: yes our files might have some empty lines but how can I fix this ?

Comment: ps .. I'm not a python expert nor a developer Sorry T.T (unfortunately)

Comment: Look to see if the line has one first. Try `in`.

Comment: oh .. there's millions of empty lines in this files. Where should I put the 'in' ??

Comment: In an `if` statement before you try splitting.